# Is it kosher to send RTP audio and DTMF events at the same time?

Tags: asterisk, voip, rtp, dtmf

I am sending an audio stream over RTP, and at the same time ought to send some DTMF events to control a switch on the other end.

First of all, from the RTP standard, is it allowed to send continuous uninterrupted audio *and* events overlapping in time? I am reading [RFC3550](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3550.txt), [RFC3551](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3551.txt) and [RFC4733](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4733.txt), and not seeing anything that would specifically mention that this is allowed, while not really expressly prohibiting this.

The usage of the marker bit might be confusing. Namely, it is used in non-frame audio payload (I am using u-law pcm) to indicate first frame after a discontinuity, while in RFC4733 events the same mark bit marks the beginning of an event. Nowhere I can also find a mention of stream multiplexing.

Next of all, a practical consideration. Even if standard allows this, is it risky/uncommon in practice? I am controlling Asterisk features through its feature map (`features.conf`). All phones and the PJSIP library mute audio stream during a DTMF event.

Finally, if the standard allows that and Asterisk is not certainly known to go crazy from such payload intermixing, what is the correct way to stream it? What I am thinking of, is this (assuming, for the sake of example only, that PCM audio payload length is 100 samples = 100 ticks, and DTMF events are 300 ticks long):

```
Seq = 10, Timestamp = 1000, M = 0, Payload = PCM
Seq = 11, Timestamp = 1000, M = 1, Payload = DTMF: '*'; duration = 100
Seq = 12, Timestamp = 1100, M = 0, Payload = PCM 
Seq = 13, Timestamp = 1000, M = 0, Payload = DTMF: '*'; duration = 200
Seq = 14, Timestamp = 1200, M = 0, Payload = PCM 
Seq = 13, Timestamp = 1000, M = 0, Payload = DTMF: '*'; duration = 300; E = 1
```

Would that be a correct stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4733 says that in case of inband dtmf, you should send dtmf 'instead' of audio data.
you increment seqNo and TS at the same rate but the payload would be dtmf data.

If the remote UE supports playout of dtmf tones, it will playout the tone. else it will just discard dtmf payloads (unknown or unsupported)

Comment: I see. The overall impression is that the whole of RTP is written in an assumption of a single stream of media, different formats being only alternative representations of the media. I think you are right, and this statement in the standard should be taken in its widest sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are no any problem.

If you have rtc2833 , you just send rtp packets in current order and other packet with dtmf.

If you have inband dtmf, you mix audio and rtp in one packet(quality of recognition can be decreased)

If you have sip_info dtmf, you just send sip message with dtmf and rtp in current order.

Comment: Дякую. :) I take it you are answering my practical questions (the 2nd and 3rd). Do you have any pointers or evidence to elaborate? I understand that you know that Asterisk will not be unhappy seeing an RTP stream with audio and DTMF packets intertwined. Could you suggest a testing scenario that I might run to confirm everything is good in my setting? The problem is, we are using pjsip on the client, and the library clearly drops PCM frames on the floor when there is dtmf queued for output. A couple of hardware phones did same. Just wondering what's my best option to do a quick test.

Comment: That depend of dtmf standart you using. Try enable asterisk debug and dtmf debug and see whats happens. Maybe you need help of linux/asterisk guru to interpret results. There are no diff for asterisk if you doing as standart say. Except inband method, which can greatly decrease quality because of non-dtmf frames.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is where the whole problem is. It is not the shortage of asterisk or linux gurus, but rather no idea whether the standard allows that, and no way to run a test without quite a coding exercise around and deeply in the pjsip library... :(

Comment: I have nothing to add except i say above. I think pjsip lib already have all dtmf realized.

Comment: What you think is wrong. I have packet captures that show that pjsip's implementation drops audio while sending DTMF events. A quick look at its source also proves it indeed does that by design. See https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/browser/pjproject/trunk/pjmedia/src/pjmedia/stream.c#L1226 - if there is anything in the DTMF queue, audio frames are dropped on the floor with a loud bang.

Comment: Change mode to sip_info. Not think it can do drop in that mode. Anyway that is not programming question, that is bug in pjsip.